# How to use multiple count in same block in terraform

Tags: terraform, openstack, terraform0.12+

My variables.tf is having required variables:

I have the a block in terraform code which has variable count defined. I need to run through a for loop which should start with index based on count.index value and iterate through var1 number of times.

I could not fit in with for_each or for because I need to iterate through a count. But there is already a count variable defined in the same block so I cannot define another count within the block.

It would be really helpful if someone help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, simply put, it cannot be done that way, i.e., two `count` statements are not supported.

Comment: Also, where did the `locals` blocks come from? I don't see them in the provider documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_v2.

Comment: It's still not clear because the locals can be used but not sure where and how you would want to use them.

Comment: @MarkoE I need a local variable inside openstack_instance_v2 which  has the value based on count.index value. But openstack_instance_v2 does not support locals block and it can't be defined in variables.tf as it will differe based on count.index

Comment: Ok, but which arguments of the resource would use the local or any other variable?

Comment: @MarkoE I need to construct the output_value and add it to metadata in openstacn_compute_instance_v2 resource

Comment: Sadly your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully I am able to achieve the use case I described using range function terraform. Eg- pseudo code:

```
for n in range(var.private_count) : "output_value" => join(",",openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.floatip[required_index+i].address }
```